# JavaFX and SerialPort

Tags: java, javafx, serial-port

I wrote an application in JavaFX and I want to open a port to connect to Arduino:

`SerialPort port = new SerialPort ("PORT");`

When I open the port:

`port.openPort ();`

I get the following problem (when I comment this line of code the problem disappears):

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=5544, tid=7360
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.1+12) (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\path
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

It uses JavaFX17 and Java 17. Could someone please help?

Comment: Which serial port are you trying to open with `port.openPort ();`? You are passing a String `"PORT"` to the SerialPort() constructor. I don't think `"PORT"` is a name of any port!

Answer (score 0):

You must use the correct port name.

The name of the COM port can be viewed in the Arduino IDE, or in the device manager.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).